# Electron fails to install on CI

Tags: javascript, electron, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

After we migrated to Electron v11 for our project from v6, we started experiencing weird CI issues, where Electron did not install properly and the pipeline failed.

Our setup:

- Lerna
- Monorepo
- Yarn v1.22
- Private npm registry

Example of such issues:

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /builds/xxxx/..../node_modules/electron, /builds/.../node_modules/electron, /builds/xxxx/app/node_modules/electron: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /builds/xxxx/features/yyyy/node_modules/electron
Output:
Error: dest already exists.
    at /builds/xxxx/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move/move.js:41:31
```

```
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\gitlab\builds\pFMTxHs3\0\xxxxxx\features\yyyyy\node_modules\electron
Output:
C:\gitlab\builds\pFMTxHs3\0\xxxx\features\yyyyy\node_modules\electron\install.js:51
  throw err
  ^
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\electron\Cache\httpsgithub.comelectronelectronreleasesdownloadv7.1.4electron-v7.1.4-win32-x64.zip\electron-v7.1.4-win32-x64.zip'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\electron\\Cache\\httpsgithub.comelectronelectronreleasesdownloadv7.1.4electron-v7.1.4-win32-x64.zip\\electron-v7.1.4-win32-x64.zip'
```

We tried deleting CI caches, Yarn caches, NPM caches all of that worked inconsistently. Sometimes we would have successful pipelines, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of months battling with this ghost, we had another error `5xx` upon trying to download electron. It suddenly stopped downloading everywhere local machines and CI.

After getting in touch with the Electron team I discovered the problem.

We had a very old `.npmrc` config, which was no longer valid.

It contained this:

```
disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron
```

When I've changed the line into this:

```
disturl=https://electronjs.org/headers
```

All of our pain was gone - our builds became stable again.

Big thanks to the electron community!